# Javascript regular expression for year

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am pretty new to javascript. How would I find if a piece of text **contains** a four digit year?

For example:

```
var copyright = $('#copyright').val();
if \d{4} in copyright:
    do something
```

Comment: Would you consider `9876` as a year? Or can you be certain that **if** there is a four digit number, it will be a year? To get you started with JS and regular expressions, have a look at [MDN - Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Comment: The `val()` method is meant to be used with input elements. From your description `copyright` doesn't appear to be an input element. Is it possible you meant the `text()` method instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do it...

```
var isValidYear = /\d{4}/.test(str);
```

It looks like this is user input, so you might want to trim the string before you try to validate it with this regex. Alternatively, add a `\s*` to either side between the start and end anchors, and it will be close enough to `trim()`/`$.trim()` for you (it won't also kill unprintable control characters).

Alternatively, if you wanted to test if the year was a valid year (at least as valid as what JavaScript can handle), you could do...

```
var isValidYear = ! isNaN(new Date(str, 0, 1));
```

Though on my Chrome, this will assume `xx` is `19xx` and handles dates over four decimal digits.

Comment: That would validate '1234a', I think you need to set `^` and `$` (start/end) as well.

Comment: The question was whether or not the text _contains_ a year, so you should remove the `^$` anchors.

Comment: If the year is indeed contained within the text, running the entire text through the `Date` constructor would result in an error. You should first `match()` and retrieve the year within the text.

Comment: @Boaz That was the intention :)

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't follow. Where is the match being retrieved?

Comment: @Boaz I didn't include the relevant code in my example. It was the intention of `str` to be a year.

Answer (score 1):

```
var copyright = $('#copyright').val();
if ( /^\d{4}$/.test(copyright) ) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: I think the question was whether it _contains_ a year, in which case having the `^$` anchors is wrong.

Comment: I just realized that, although I’m keeping this answer just in case the OP meant to validate the entire input against 4 digits.